# Complex sub-setting on a row by row basis using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data file (.csv) file that I need to import using Pandas, subset some of the data, and export. However, I'm struggling with the sub-setting problem. I've re-created the data in Pandas so that anyone can work with it (below).

My dataframe contains 4 columns; out_type_1, smd_1, out_type_2, and smd_2. You can think of the smd_1 values as being directly linked (conceptually) to out_type_1, and the same for smd_2 and out_type_2. Both out_type columns contain either missing data, or an array containing one or more of multiple options. The array option I'm interested in is 'a'.

Keeping in mind that the smd_ and out_type columns are conceptually linked, I need to subset this data frame such that every out_type value that contains 'a' is saved to a new column, alongside its corresponding smd_ value. This search can be done on a row by row basis, and only one column per row will contain the 'a' label. Crucially, in future datasets of this kind, the number of out_type and smd_ columns will vary, and many will include more of them.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'out_type_1': [['a', 'Reading primary outcome'], ['a', 'Other outcome'], ['a', 'Reading primary outcome'], 
                       ['a', 'Reading primary outcome'], ['a', 'Other outcome'], ['a', 'Other outcome'], 
                       ['a', 'Other outcome'], ['a', 'Other outcome'], ['Other outcome'], ['Other outcome'], 
                       ['a', 'Other outcome'], ['a', 'Reading primary outcome'], ['a', 'Reading primary outcome'], 
                       ['a', 'Other outcome'], ['a', 'Reading primary outcome'], ['Reading primary outcome'], 
                       ['a', 'Reading primary outcome'], None, None, ['a', 'Other outcome'], ['a', 'Reading primary outcome'], 
                       ['a', 'Reading primary outcome'], ['a', 'Other outcome']], 
        'smd_1': [-0.045, 0.0478, 0.1843, 0.0534, -0.0465, 0.2039, 0.6767, 0.5996, 0, 0.0517, 0.0922, 0.0631, 0.184, 0.1258, 0.2, -0.1982, 0.5207, 0.0187, 0.1245, 0.9315, 0.3784, 0.5811, 0.3998], 
        'out_type_2': [['Other outcome'], ['Other outcome'], ['Other outcome'], ['Other outcome'], None, None, None, None, 
                       ['a', 'Reading primary outcome'], ['a', 'Reading primary outcome'], ['Other outcome'], 
                       ['Mathematics primary outcome'], ['Other outcome'], ['Mathematics primary outcome'], 
                       ['Mathematics primary outcome'], ['a', 'Mathematics primary outcome'], None, None, None, None, 
                       ['Mathematics primary outcome'], ['Other outcome'], ['Other outcome']], 
        'smd_2': [0.9197, 0.1541, 0.1229, -0.1277, None, None, None, None, -0.1, -0.04, 0.5401, 0.174, 0.2519, 0.0193, 0.49, -0.0209, None, 0.1801, 0.0199, None, 0.5347, -0.1127, 0.3197]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

It's quite a tricky problem to describe, so I've created what would be the desired subset data frame for this particular example:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'out_type_subset': [
        "['a', 'Reading primary outcome']",
        "['a', 'Other outcome']",
        "['a', 'Reading primary outcome']",
        "['a', 'Reading primary outcome']",
        "['a', 'Other outcome']",
        "['a', 'Other outcome']",
        "['a', 'Other outcome']",
        "['a', 'Other outcome']",
        "['a', 'Reading primary outcome']",
        "['a, 'Reading primary outcome']",
        "['a', 'Other outcome']",
        "['a', 'Reading primary outcome']",
        "['a', 'Reading primary outcome']",
        "['a', 'Other outcome']",
        "['a’, 'Reading primary outcome']",
        "['a', 'Mathematics primary outcome']",
        "['a', 'Reading primary outcome']",
        "NA",
        "NA",
        "['a', 'Other outcome']",
        "['a', 'Reading primary outcome']",
        "['a', 'Reading primary outcome']",
        "['a', 'Other outcome']"
    ],
    'smd_subset': [
        -0.045,
        0.0478,
        0.1843,
        0.0534,
        -0.0465,
        0.2039,
        0.6767,
        0.5996,
        -0.1,
        -0.04,
        0.0922,
        0.0631,
        0.184,
        0.1258,
        0.2,
        -0.0209,
        0.5207,
        None,
        None,
        0.9315,
        0.3784,
        0.5811,
        0.3998
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

To summarize, I want to 'grab' all cell values that contain 'a' as well as their corresponding smd_ values in the column immediate to its right, and stack them vertically, keeping NA for rows that contain no 'a' at all. I'm finding this particularly challenging to think about, especially as searching for a string 'a' in an array in a cell is proving challenging in and of itself.

Comment: What happens if both `out_type_1` and `out_type_2` both contain `'a'`? Also, is `out_type_2` supposed to be in a nested array or is that a copying error? For example, is `[[a, Reading primary outcome]]` supposed to be `[a, Reading primary outcome]`? @Beatdown

Comment: out_type_1 and out_type_2 will never both contain 'a'. Regardless of how many out_type_x columns there are, there will only ever be one 'a' per row. The [[ ]] you mentioned was a copying error, thanks for spotting -- edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes some assumptions that your example is good representation of how the data is laid out and the columns are titled. If not, I think you can use this as a basis for your data. Comments in line.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#find your out_type columns to iterate over
col_list = df.filter(regex = 'out_type').columns.tolist() 

for c in col_list:
    # iterate over each column to find the 'a'
    # this assumes 'a' is always the first element in the list
    # adding columns (can be deleted later)
    df.loc[df[c].str[0] == 'a', 'outcol'] = c

# adding another column to identify which smd to use
df['smdcol'] = df['outcol'].str.replace('out_type','smd')

# use at to find single location based on index and column
df['out_type'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.at[x.name, x['outcol']] if pd.notnull(x['outcol']) else 'N/A', axis=1)
df['smd_value'] = df.apply(lambda x: df.at[x.name, x['smdcol']] if pd.notnull(x['outcol']) else 'N/A', axis=1)
df
```

Output

```
                      out_type_1    smd_1                        out_type_2    smd_2      outcol smdcol                          out_type smd_value
0   [a, Reading primary outcome] -0.04500                   [Other outcome]  0.91970  out_type_1  smd_1      [a, Reading primary outcome]  -0.04500
1             [a, Other outcome]  0.04780                   [Other outcome]  0.15410  out_type_1  smd_1                [a, Other outcome]   0.04780
2   [a, Reading primary outcome]  0.18430                   [Other outcome]  0.12290  out_type_1  smd_1      [a, Reading primary outcome]   0.18430
3   [a, Reading primary outcome]  0.05340                   [Other outcome] -0.12770  out_type_1  smd_1      [a, Reading primary outcome]   0.05340
4             [a, Other outcome] -0.04650                              None      NaN  out_type_1  smd_1                [a, Other outcome]  -0.04650
5             [a, Other outcome]  0.20390                              None      NaN  out_type_1  smd_1                [a, Other outcome]   0.20390
6             [a, Other outcome]  0.67670                              None      NaN  out_type_1  smd_1                [a, Other outcome]   0.67670
7             [a, Other outcome]  0.59960                              None      NaN  out_type_1  smd_1                [a, Other outcome]   0.59960
8                [Other outcome]  0.00000      [a, Reading primary outcome] -0.10000  out_type_2  smd_2      [a, Reading primary outcome]  -0.10000
9                [Other outcome]  0.05170      [a, Reading primary outcome] -0.04000  out_type_2  smd_2      [a, Reading primary outcome]  -0.04000
10            [a, Other outcome]  0.09220                   [Other outcome]  0.54010  out_type_1  smd_1                [a, Other outcome]   0.09220
11  [a, Reading primary outcome]  0.06310     [Mathematics primary outcome]  0.17400  out_type_1  smd_1      [a, Reading primary outcome]   0.06310
12  [a, Reading primary outcome]  0.18400                   [Other outcome]  0.25190  out_type_1  smd_1      [a, Reading primary outcome]   0.18400
13            [a, Other outcome]  0.12580     [Mathematics primary outcome]  0.01930  out_type_1  smd_1                [a, Other outcome]   0.12580
14  [a, Reading primary outcome]  0.20000     [Mathematics primary outcome]  0.49000  out_type_1  smd_1      [a, Reading primary outcome]   0.20000
15     [Reading primary outcome] -0.19820  [a, Mathematics primary outcome] -0.02090  out_type_2  smd_2  [a, Mathematics primary outcome]  -0.02090
16  [a, Reading primary outcome]  0.52070                              None      NaN  out_type_1  smd_1      [a, Reading primary outcome]   0.52070
17                          None  0.01870                              None  0.18010         NaN    NaN                               N/A       N/A
18                          None  0.12450                              None  0.01990         NaN    NaN                               N/A       N/A
19            [a, Other outcome]  0.93150                              None      NaN  out_type_1  smd_1                [a, Other outcome]   0.93150
20  [a, Reading primary outcome]  0.37840     [Mathematics primary outcome]  0.53470  out_type_1  smd_1      [a, Reading primary outcome]   0.37840
21  [a, Reading primary outcome]  0.58110                   [Other outcome] -0.11270  out_type_1  smd_1      [a, Reading primary outcome]   0.58110
22            [a, Other outcome]  0.39980                   [Other outcome]  0.31970  out_type_1  smd_1                [a, Other outcome]   0.39980
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a really nice solution and a lot more elegant than I thought was possible. There's quite a bit for me to dig into here too, techniques that I wasn't previously aware of. If you could remove the 't' from this line (df.loc[dft[c].str[0] == 'a', 'outcol'] = c), I will then accept the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Good catch. I was playing around with temp df and missed that one. Should be updated now.

Comment: I know it's beyond the remit of this question and so I'm happy to post another question if needed. But is there a simple change to have it so that rather than checking the first element in the array, it checks every element in the array for 'a', here: for c in col_list: df.loc[df[c].str[0] == 'a', 'outcol'] = c

Comment: It wouldn’t be as straightforward for many reasons, but using apply with a much more detailed custom function would work. Would be slower due to having to check all elements in all out_type columns until you find the ‘a’

Comment: I suggest a new question with a new dataset where the ‘a’ is in different locations in the list. You can reference back to this one.

Comment: if you replace the one line in for the loop with these three, it should work with 'a' in any position     dft = df[df[c].notnull()][c].apply(lambda x: x if 'a' in x else None)
    indexlist = dft[dft.notnull()].index
    df.loc[df.index.isin(indexlist), 'outcol'] = c

Comment: Worked nicely, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `apply`, `fillna`, `drop` and a helper function that helps find `a` as the first entry of the array. First create the `function` that will be used by `apply`:

```
# Helper function that checks if a is in array
def check_if_a(x, count):
    for i in range(1, count+1):
        out_type = 'out_type_{}'.format(i)
        smd = 'smd_{}'.format(i)
        if x[out_type] and x[out_type][0] == 'a':
          return x[[out_type, smd]]
    return np.repeat(np.nan, count*2)
```

Then use an `apply`, `fillna` and `drop`:

```
# Get the number of columns that has out_type. This assumes that out_type and smd are paired
col_count = np.sum(df.columns.str.count("out_type"))
# Apply helper function in each row of dataframe
df3 = df.apply(lambda x: check_if_a(x, col_count), axis=1)

# Use out_type_1 and smd_1 as anchors
for i in range(2, col_count+1):
  # Create out_type_subset by filling null entries in out_type_1 with entries in out_type_#
  df3['out_type_subset'] = df3['out_type_1'].fillna(df3['out_type_{}'.format(i)])
  # Create smd_subset by filling null entries in smd_1 with entries in smd_#
  df3['smd_subset'] = df3['smd_1'].fillna(df3['smd_{}'.format(i)])

# Drop columns that are no longer used
col_to_rm = []
for i in range(1, col_count+1):
   col_to_rm.append('out_type_{}'.format(i))
   col_to_rm.append('smd_{}'.format(i))
df3 = df3.drop(columns=col_to_rm)
```

df3 is the desired dataframe that you mention in your question:

```
                     out_type_subset  smd_subset
0       [a, Reading primary outcome]     -0.0450
1                 [a, Other outcome]      0.0478
2       [a, Reading primary outcome]      0.1843
3       [a, Reading primary outcome]      0.0534
4                 [a, Other outcome]     -0.0465
5                 [a, Other outcome]      0.2039
6                 [a, Other outcome]      0.6767
7                 [a, Other outcome]      0.5996
8       [a, Reading primary outcome]     -0.1000
9       [a, Reading primary outcome]     -0.0400
10                [a, Other outcome]      0.0922
11      [a, Reading primary outcome]      0.0631
12      [a, Reading primary outcome]      0.1840
13                [a, Other outcome]      0.1258
14      [a, Reading primary outcome]      0.2000
15  [a, Mathematics primary outcome]     -0.0209
16      [a, Reading primary outcome]      0.5207
17                               NaN         NaN
18                               NaN         NaN
19                [a, Other outcome]      0.9315
20      [a, Reading primary outcome]      0.3784
21      [a, Reading primary outcome]      0.5811
22                [a, Other outcome]      0.3998
```

Comment: The only issue here is, for future datasets, the number of "out_type_x" and smd_x columns will vary. This one has 2, but there may be several more to check in other datasets. I need something that will dynamically check all columns without me needing to hard code more elif statements.

Comment: @Beatdown, I've changed the code to make it more dynamic. The assumption that it makes is that `out_type_x` and `smd_x` **are paired** and that `out_type_x` and `smd_x` **start** at 1 and **ascend** by intervals of one.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you upvote the answer if it answered your question.